# Simple java, String length

Tags: java, string, oop, inheritance, interface

I am finding it difficult to return a String length as "*" Symbols. The method noDisclosure is in an Interface and TopClearance is a subclass of Clearance.Also, the gettermethod getSecret() is in the superClass-->Clearance so I already inherited it.

I know that returning a String is using Str.length() but I just don't know how to take the length and convert it into "*"

Here is part of the question.

The method noDisclosure in TopClearance will return a sequence of the symbol '*' as long as the secret in Clearance.
Hence if for example top is the name of an instance of TopClearance and top.getSecret() is "magic" then 
top.noDisclosure() will return "*****" because "magic" has length 5.
The method passport in TopClearance will return the first two characters of the name in Clearance.
Hence if for example top is the name of an instance of TopClearance and top.getName() is "Mark" then 
top.passport() will return "Ma".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can a for loop for `noDisclosure` to mask the word:

```
String maskedWord = "";
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    maskedWord += "*";
}
```

For `passport`, you can use the `substring` method to obtain a piece of the name:

```
String shortenedName = name.substring(0, 2);
```

Comment: It gets the job done (and is maybe the most logical), but you wouldn't want to do this. Also if you would do it this way then at least use a StringBuilder rather than String concat.

Comment: I didn't know how in depth they've gone with Strings, so I thought I would provide a simpler solution and let others offer other ideas too.

Comment: I am not really advanced in terms of programming so I think this method is logical. Thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the String.replaceAll() method, which uses Regular Expression, where . represents any character:

```
text.replaceAll(".", "*");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new string using the known word length:

```
String maskedWord = new String(new char[word.length()]).replace("\0", "*");
```